# Chromecast is amazingly inconsistent

Tags: chromecast

I've been trying to troubleshoot my ChromeCast with Google the past couple of weeks or so, but we're going in circles at this point.  I've followed the docs and have the router setup with the required wifi options (originally UPNP was disabled and had to be turned on).  Looking for more ideas.

Some (rare) days the Chromecast works perfectly fine.  Other days it will only accept casting from full screen Chrome tabs (and refuse app casting).  Other days it will not accept casting from anything (devices will show it as available, but when you go to connect will then throw "Device not found null" error) eventually followed by "Something has gone wrong" on the TV screen.  Still other days it will boot up and connect to wifi (I can ping it from other devices on the network), but it says no Internet found (every other wifi device we have is working fine on the Internet).  Most times Home will connect to it, but occasionally Home will list it, but fail if you try to access options.

It's always got a full strong / all bars wifi connection.  I'm on a standard Arris router just like pretty much everyone else that has my ISP locally.  No problems with connectivity from anything else, seems to just be the Chromecast.  Firmware is up to date.  Rebooting client devices and router seem to have no impact.  Same can be said for the Chromecast itself.  If it's not working today, it's probably going to stay broken for the rest of the day.  Tomorrow *may* bring better luck though...

Comment: Do you happen to have the router providing 5G and 2.4G on the same SSID? When I did this it got really confused and was a pain to get working, apps wouldn't even see it sometimes etc. As soon as I set it up with seperate ssid's then left it on the 2.4ghz connection, it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't have options for more than one SSID.  Reading about 802.11n it sounds like 5 ghz is a required part of the protocol, but I can't find any reference to anything other than 2.4 ghz with this router?

Comment: 802.11n can support both 5ghz and 2.4ghz. If your router is picky about what it does, that sucks for you and that router. Options could be a better router, or maybe there's some fix for the chromecast to fix this issue but I never discovered it.

Comment: Was able to get a wifi analyzer going and found that I don't have 5 ghz.  It's a 2.4 ghz only router.  Good to know.  Albeit a bit disappointing.  Fine tuned my channel selection and width around all the other local routers.  Absolutely no difference for the Chromecast though.

Comment: Ok then it's not the same problem I had, not sure what else you can try then :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up pulling an ethernet cable to that room and setting up a NetGear Extender in AP mode on 5 ghz only, right next to the Chromecast, and connecting the Chromecast to that AP.  No more issues with the Chromecast.  $200 fix to make a $50 device work.  :D

As a side benefit, before whenever the Chromecast was powered it up it interfered with OTA television to the point I put the Chromecast on a powerstrip so I could turn it off when I didn't need it.  Now that it's on 5ghz instead of 2.4ghz my OTA signals are no longer disrupted by the Chromecast!